# cygwin doesn't recognize config.guess when installing Haskell package

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, haskell

I am trying to install a Haskell package on Windows 10 64-bit. I installed cygwin for x64 architecture. Later I installed `automake-1.15` using cygwin's setup file. I downloaded the latest `config.guess` and `config.sub` files and put them in the `automake-1.15` directory. However, I am still unable to configure the Haskell package successfully.

```
Configuring plugins-1.5.5.0...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler, --with-gcc
checking build system type... ./config.guess: unable to guess system type

This script, last modified 2002-07-23, has failed to recognize
the operating system you are using. It is advised that you
download the most up to date version of the config scripts from

    ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/config/

If the version you run (./config.guess) is already up to date, please
send the following data and any information you think might be
pertinent to <config-patches@gnu.org> in order to provide the needed
information to handle your system.

config.guess timestamp = 2002-07-23
```

Before replacing the `config.guess` and `config.sub` files, the timestamp of `config.guess` was somewhere in the year 2014, but the configuration message also showed `2002-07-23`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Install Automake and Autoconf (all versions preferred),
and reinstall automake-1.15 just in case.

Before running `configure` run `autoreconf -ifv`. This should install latest config.guess on your source tree